# What happened to the rest of masechet Meilah -- it ends at 22a but the daf yomi calendar says it goes to 37?

Tags: talmud-bavli, english, kodshim, maseches-meila

[This daf yomi calendar](http://www.dafyomi.org/machzor.php) says that Meilah goes to 37, so I was surprised to discover that my digital copy of the Soncino edition of talmud ends it at 22a.  This is also true of [the copy at halakhah.com](http://halakhah.com), so I'm guessing this isn't just a problem in what was bundled up for digital distribution.  (I don't have a print copy to refer to.)  The point-by-point summary at [dafyomi.co.il](http://%22http://www.dafyomi.co.il/meilah/points/points.htm) also ends early.

What's going on?  If there's more to this tractate, where can I find it in translation short of going out and buying a print volume?

Comment: There are only 22a pages in Meilah. 23-37 are actually the other masechtot of Kinim, Tamid and Middot. See [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14186/759) for why they were printed all together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @DoubleAA said in the comment, Meilah is only 22 pages. The next Talmidic Tractate is Tamid. You can find the PDF here: http://www.halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Tamid.pdf

Notice that the page numbering does not restart at 2A, but rather starts at 25B.

As @Alex noted in [his comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14186/shkalim-kinim-midos-in-daf-yomi#comment25686_14188), in between Meila and Tamid are the Mishnayot (with no Talmudic Commentary) of Kinnim. Here is the [Soncino Tranlation of Kinnim](http://www.halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Kinim.pdf), although it is not split up by Talmudic page.

After Tamid goes Midot. [Here is the Soncino Translation](http://www.halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Middoth.pdf), once again not split up by Talmudic page.