# Tractate Shekalim and Daf Yomi

Tags: history, daf-yomi, tractate-shekalim

Tractate Shekalim is the only tractate of Yerushalmi included in the Daf Yomi cycle.

I assume this is because it was the only lonesome tractate of Seder Moed which did not have Bavli on it, so to complete the Seder they included it.

Is there verification (or refutation) of this theory, or is there another explanation?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25939/759