# Why is Eduyos in the Daf Yomi cycle?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, daf-yomi, eduyot

There are several masechtos included in the printed versions of Talmud Bavli that, in fact, don't have any Bavli on them: Yerushalmi Shekalim, Mishnayos Eduyos, Mishnayos Kinnim, Mishnayos Tamid (for half of the masechta), and Mishnayos Middos.

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14186/shkalim-kinim-midos-in-daf-yomi) addresses why Shekalim, Kinnim, and Middos are included. Tamid is fairly obvious: once we've started the masechta with Gemara, we might as well finish it, even if the end doesn't have Gemara; there's no need to split the masechta in half.

But why is Eduyos included? Neither of the answers given in the above link help; there's still Avos, which is also in Nezikin but not included in Shas Bavli, so it's not just to round out the Seder. And Eduyos doesn't discuss anything related to the Beis HaMikdash (at least as its primary focus), so that can't be the reason either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eduyot is not included in the standard daf yomi cycle (possibly for the very reasons you cite in your question).

See the current cycle's full calendar [here](https://dafyomi.co.il/calendars/calendar13.htm) and note that Eduyot does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

1- The above person is correct and the correct answer to the question should be" it is not in the daf yomi cycle"
2- As to why it's printed in a Bavli a) Most editions of Bavli I've seen print all mishnayos . Possibly however, those are modern printings, and old printings print a select few
B) if this is so it is quite obvious why eduyos should be printed. It is constantly quoted , complimented, and usually paskened like." Hoeel utnan bbicheerta kavasay". The Halacha follows the opinion quoted in eduyos since eduyos is the chosen tractate. Chosen Since all opinions in eduyos were given as testimony heard directly from earlier scholars. Both because it was referred to as the chosen one and  it's often necessary or at least helpful to look up while studying other masechtas,  it was printed in Bavli